# How can I run Python code using Informatica command tasks

Tags: python, informatica

I'm attempting to run a Python script using an Informatica command task to scrape data from the web. Each time I start the workflow I get the error:

> Command task instance [c_Run_Code]: execution of command [Test_Scrape] did not complete successfully with exit code [1]

I'm using the hash-bang: `#!C\Python27\python.exe` as the first line in the code, and the command I'm issuing is:

```
C\Python27\python.exe C\Documents\Python\Test_Scrape.py
```

Why do I continuously get this error?

Comment: Does `Test_Scrape.py` otherwise work correctly?

Comment: Do you have an error message? A non-0 exit code is telling you the script encountered an error. My guess is that the environment is different between when you run the script and when it is run by your scheduler (i.e., a package isn't available in the python path that the script is expecting)

Comment: Test_Scrape.py runs without error when I run it from the command line, all packages are installed properly so there shouldn't be an error when run

Comment: Can you check the exact command that Informatica is running. It should be there in the workflow log. Also, check if the id Informatica is using has appropriate access to python executable and the script.

Comment: The exact command python is running is: Command task instance [c_Run_Code]: running command [Test_Scrape], with command value [cmd /c "C\Python27\python.exe C\Documents\Python\Test_Scrape.py"].  I'm not sure how to check if the id has appropriate access to the script

Comment: After running the command from the command line, could you run the following command $? advise if you get a return of anything other than 0

Comment: Silly question: is the script and python installed on Informatica server that executes the workflow? Those paths are local from server perspective.

Comment: Even more silly question - why is there no colon `:` in all the paths? What environment are you using?

Comment: Yes, both python 2.7 and the script are installed on the server so there shouldn't be an error. The environment I'm using is a work environment, but it doesn't need to use colons when accessing files and directories (C in this case will denote the full path to the python interpreter and the script)

Comment: A development I've made points toward Informatica not reading the site-packages Library. I'm not sure why but this appears to be the cause of the error.

Comment: I have found and fixed the problem. For those wishing to do something similar: either wrap the command in a batch or powershell file, or ensure that the python version installed has been added to the PATH.

Comment: @Sean then write an answer. Interesting that PATH has anything to do with it since you explicitely called python with the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found and fixed the problem. For those wishing to do something similar: either wrap the command in a batch or powershell file, or ensure that the python version installed has been added to the PATH.