# trigger python script using Informatica BDM command task

Tags: python, informatica

I would like to run a python script using **informatica BDM** command task, can any one please help in how to trigger it.

Thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118152/how-can-i-run-python-code-using-informatica-command-tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a command from command line take in `BDM` place your command as below:

```
Python /Script_path/script_name.py ${par:argument1}
```

Here `argument1` is the defined workflow level parameter and can be passed from a parameter file. It is optional.